# Webstorm localhost debugging

Tags: jquery, html, debugging, webstorm

My webstorm suddenly stopped debugging in Chrome. The port and settings are correct, or atlest they appear to me. This was working until a few days back but stopped working today. I tried to retrace any changes to machine, but none of that would have impacted.

It appears that the specified port is somehow blocked on my machine because after I run my project it error's out with following error:

- Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
- Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 (Fiddler - Connection Failed)

Naturally I checked fiddler and the following error pops out

271 502 HTTP    127.0.0.1:63342 /browserConnection/buildInfo    512 no-cache, must-revalidate   text/html; charset=UTF-8    chrome:18024

GET /browserConnection/buildInfo HTTP/1.1

[Fiddler] The connection to '127.0.0.1' failed. 
Error: ConnectionRefused (0x274d). 
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:63342

Anyone got an idea what's happing because I tried everything I could think of.

Comment: seems the port 63342 is blocked for some reason - may be a firewall or anti-virus-related problem. See https://www.smartftp.com/support/kb/connection-refused-f58.html, for example. I can suggest to set some free port, like 8090, in both extension settings in Chrome and JavaScript Debugger settings - they will be used instead of default ones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by setting the debugging port 8090 and disable external connections checkbox

Comment: 'Can accept external connections' option is likely the reason for your issue - with this option enabled, the default port (63342) can't be used for security reasons. So normally you need to either disable this option or change the port

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by changing "localhost" by "127.0.0.1"

http://**127.0.0.1**:63342/test/index.html